# My component doesnt load joomla template but its working on local

Tags: templates, joomla, components

I have a problem ! i have one component named com_artist ! It's all fine at local machine ! But problem raised on server file ! i have upload database and all files  on server too but it's not working ! Main problem is that  all code inside component is running but it doesn't load my joomla template !

Comment: Have you enabled error reporting and checks for any errors? You need to provide more information else we will not be able to answer your question

Comment: Yes ! i already check that !! Joomla is not showing any error !!  i am new to joomla ! is any module can effect towards component ? What type of information is needed?

Comment: Did you update the server instances database or replicate the admin panel actions to enable template and install custom component?

Comment: I have checked my all possible bugs and problems but still in problem! :( But i found one more hints about this, that is Instead of loading my template joomla load it's system template. I don't know more about why joomla loads system template instead of loading my assigned template! :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes Finally Solved :) Silly mistake :D, that was template name is in Uppercase in one of php file that's why linux server could not load joomla template because my template folder name is in lowercase ! :) –